# Stuck while solving systems of linear differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the following differential equation:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=-3x+y-8 \\ \frac{dy}{dt}=x-3y+8. $

I first rewrote the equations using the differential operator $D=\frac{d}{dt}$ and eliminated the variable $y$.

\begin{equation}
(D+3)x-y=-8, \\x+(D+3)y=8.
\end{equation}

therefore

$ (D^2+6D+8)x=-8D(1)-16$

which is equivalent to

\begin{equation}
\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}+6\frac{dx}{dt}+8x=-8\frac{d(1)}{dt}-16.
\end{equation}

But the equation is not homogeneous! How would you solve it? Any help regardless of its form or length will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

$$\dfrac{dx}{dt}=-3x+y-8 \\ \dfrac{dy}{dt}=x-3y+8$$

From the first equation we have

$$y = x' + 3x + 8 \implies y' = x'' + 3 x'$$

Substituting into the second equation, we have

$$x'' + 3 x = x - 3(x' + 3x + 8) + 8$$

Simplifying

$$x'' + 6 x' + 8 x + 16 = 0$$

This results in

$$x(t) = c_1 e^{-4 t}+c_2 e^{-2 t}-2$$

You can use this result to find $y(t)$.

There are many other ways to solve these types of problems, but I used your approach.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I wish I had more time to study the theory of ODEs...